# 24 game... with exponents!

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

You may have seen the 24 game where you take four numbers and try to make 24 using the numbers and mathematical operations. However, I present a twist on the 24 game: with an exponent. Here are the modified rules:

1. You must use each of the four numbers exactly once.
2. You may use only the following mathematical operations: `()`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `^` (exponent).
3. You may only use exponents of integral powers, exponents of (1/integer) powers, and not anything that evaluates to `-1`, `0`, and `1`.
4. You must use *exactly* one exponent.

Here are the problems:

1. `6 4 1 1` (you should get this one in a few seconds)
2. `1 1 9 9`
3. `9 8 7 3`
4. `4/7 3 5 11`
5. `3/17 2 4 4`
6. `3/16 4/5 5 2`
7. `1/7 1/6 2/3 2`
8. `3 12 90 105`
9. `2 3 14 39`
10. `3 28 20 16` (the day this was posted)

Comment: Does "not `-1`, `0`, and `1`" mean that those can't be the exponents, or those can't be the bases of exponents?

Comment: Those can't be the powers.

Comment: So basically every one of them has to have an exponent?

Comment: Yes, exactly one of them.

Comment: Good point, fixed.

Comment: Think you should also put whether or not $\sqrt\,$ or $!$ is allowed in the question.

Comment: And I assume we can't put two number together to make another number? (e.g. `1` & `5` to make `15`)

Comment: And, what, the exponent can be any *new* number? If so, you should've said so explicitly. And maybe given an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`6 4 1 1`

> $6*4*(1^2)*1$

`1 1 9 9`

> $9^{1/2}*(9-1)*1$

`9 8 7 3`

> $((9+7)/8)^3*3$

`4/7 3 5 11`

> $\frac{4}{7}*(5^2-11)*3$

`3/17 2 4 4`

> $(4^3+4)*\frac{3}{17}*2$

`3/16 4/5 5 2`

> $2^5 * \frac{3}{16} * \frac{4}{5} * 5$

`1/7 1/6 2/3 2`

> $2^2/\frac{1}{7} - \frac{2/3}{1/6}$

`3 12 90 105`

> $(105 - 90 - 12)^3-3$

`2 3 14 39`

> $39 - 14 - (3-2)^2$

`3 28 20 16`

> $\frac{16}{28-20}^3 *3$

Comment: Almost there, but on number 9, you cannot use the first power.

Comment: Power 2 also works ;)

Comment: How can this be an accepted answer?  One of the rules is "You may only use exponents of integral powers" yet in the second answer, the exponent is $\frac{1}{2}$ - clearly not an integer.  Don't want to take away from the answer - great work finding solutions for them all.  I just think that the puzzle is misrepresented.

Comment: read again the question : You may only use exponents of integral powers, exponents of (1/integer) powers. This is not really clear but the ',' means 'or'

Comment: @Lordofdark Dammit!  I didn't see that.  Thanks!